# How to reset a file input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a messaging system and I am adding file sending, The only problem I have is that when I submit a file, I have to click on it again to set the "file chosen" part of the input to nothing, because if I don't it doesn't work.

Here is my code :
Html :

```
<div id="message_area" class="group-chat" onKeyPress="return detect_message(event)">
      <input type="text" id="message_input" name="message" placeholder="Send a message">
      <input type="hidden" id="group_id" name="group_id" value="<?php echo "{$_GET['id']}";?>">
      <label for="file"> <div style="background-image: url(../images/plus.png); height: 40px; width: 40px; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; bottom: 17.5px; position: fixed; right: 10px; z-index: 1000;">     </div> </label>
      <input type="file" id="file" onclick="bro()"name="file" value="FILE UPLOAD" style="opacity: 0;z-index: 100000; bottom: 17.5px; position: fixed; right: 10px;">
    </div>
```

Js:

```
      function Myhandlerfunction() {
      var file = this.files[0];

      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("file", file);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
      var fullurl = '../backend/sendvideosandimages.php?id=' + group_id;
        xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (this.status == 200) {
          };
      };
      xhr.send(fd);
    };
    function bro() {
    document.querySelector('#file').removeEventListener('change', Myhandlerfunction, true);
    document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', Myhandlerfunction , true);
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just set `input.value("")` to empty like any other input filed after sending...

Comment: You can do just `document.getElementbyid("file").value("FILE UPLOAD")`, i see now you have FILE UPLOAD there, so just set back to that, or empty.. . Just be careful to set it AFTER successful upload.